# Can Hibernate return a null object when using createSQLQuery() to join tables?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join

I have three tables/classes which I'm fetching with a left outer join.  I'm executing the following query:

```
List<Object[]> l = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* " +
     " FROM (table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.some_id = b.some_id) " +
     " LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c c ON c.some_id = a.some_id"
).addEntity("a", A.class).addEntity("b", B.class).addEntity("c", C.class).list();
```

The query fails when rows in A and B exist but there is no corresponding row in C, as hibernate tries to assign null values to non-null attributes in C (I can't change these attributes to be nullable).  Is there a setting in hibernate to return a null object for C if a row in C does not exist rather than trying to create an object with null values?

Comment: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies. Have you tried setting `lazy=true`? Not sure, if this helps.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't understand wrong. you are trying to get result if c is null or not null anyway.

you can add this to where clause like this:

```
and ((c.name=1234 and c.price=1234) or c.id is null)
```